# Corner detection using opencv and ROS

Tags: ros, opencv, libopencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I have implemented an algorithm that uses the opencv2 Harris corner detector. I have a few questions, but first let me explain my system: I have copied the opencv2 Harris corner detector and placed it in a callback function in which messages of type `sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg` are passed to it. I then instantiate a `cv_bridge::CvImagePtr` object and call it `cv_ptr`, the message (`msg`) is then copied to `cv_ptr` using the `cv_bridge`. I then declare `Mat dst, dst_norm, dst_norm_scaled` and a number of operations are performed and the final image (with the corners detected) is stored in `dst_norm_scaled`. When `rosmake` and then `roslaunch` it works, and I am able to view the `dst_norm_scaled` using `cv::imshow`. However I have a number of concerns:

1- If I want to transfer this back to a ROS type image, `image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());` is used, however, my corner detected image is stored in `dst_norm_scaled` now, so how do I convert and publish this?

2- I tried to use a second `cv_bridge::CvImagePtr` object I called `cv_ptr2` in which I can use instead of `dst_norm_scale` and then publish it using `image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr2->toImageMsg())`, and although `rosmake` was successful, the process died and threw an exception. I guess only 1 `cv_ptr` is allowed to be used?

3- In my program, although the corners are detected, if I move the camera too quickly there becomes a lag and sometimes the image shown becomes black for a couple of seconds. I am currently using `ros::spin()` in my main function.

If there are any additional information you would like me to explain, please let me know.
I really appreciate your help.

Regards,

Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53100/corner-detection-using-opencv-and-ros/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2013-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the publishing of data i guess you have to use cv_ptr2.image field. If you assign your dst_norm_scaled(cv::Mat i am guessing) to cv_ptr2->image  . I guess the image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg()) command should work. And there can be more than two pointers of cv_bridge, further the exception you are getting could be related to you not assigning the data properly to the pointer. For the third point i am not sure.

---

Originally posted by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) with karma: 263 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-22**:
I already tried to copy the dst_norm_scaled to the cv_ptr2 like this:
cv_ptr2->image = cvCloneImage(dst_norm_scaled);
image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
I get

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-22**:
This error: error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘const IplImage* {aka const _IplImage*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘IplImage* cvCloneImage(const IplImage*)’

**Comment by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on 2013-01-22**:
Well i guess cvCloneImage takes in as IpIImage and yours is cv::Mat so directly use cv_ptr2->image = dst_norm_scaled. post back if it works..

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-22**:
I compiled it and there is no error, I cannot test it though because the camera is not with me at the moment. I will try it later and post back, thanks alot for your help

**Comment by [Karan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2995/karan/) on 2013-01-23**:
To remove problems like this you could use IDE with Ros. Some IDEs which are generally used and there usage is documented at http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-23**:
I tried running what we discussed and the process died immediately. so I tried adding cv_ptr2 = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8); inside the try catch block and then cv_ptr2->image = dst_norm_scaled and it worked partially. When i view cvr_ptr2 with imshow it shows the correct corner image

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-01-23**:
But when I publish it on the topic /out using image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr2->toImageMsg()); and then view this using image_view, I see the image three times (in parallel). Is something going wrong with the conversion?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2016-05-19**:
did you solve the problem?